# iPhone becomes gradually hot when continue using my App

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a question about iOS App.

My iPhone becomes gradually hot when I continue using my App that I developed.

What is this cause? Is it caused by using a lot of memory or CPU？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several components inside an iPhone that can be individually activated and drain the battery and incidentally heat up due to entropy. If you go to 'Profile' in the 'Product' menu, you can launch the Instruments application and choose the 'Energy Log' instrument to run on your device. From this you can see what combination of components are on and draining power. It's likely that you are not idling as much as you could and therefore the CPU is constantly revving. Possibly this is a programming error, or maybe your app really does need it. You can then further test the CPU usage with the Time Profiler instrument.

Basically, you should always measure first with an instrument before going out and 'fixing' a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Heat is a byproduct of energy expenditure. [Apple provides a few tools for monitoring your app's energy usage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MeasuringEnergyImpact.html).  Generally speaking, lowering your CPU, GPU, “disk”, and network  usage will lower your energy usage.

Comment: Can an app damage someone's phone by heating it up too much?

Comment: Unlikely. iOS monitors the device temperatue and will take action (CPU/GPU throttling, or even system shutdown) if the device gets too hot.

Comment: Great. So hopefully my app doesn't get rejected :) -thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First post here, I hope I didn't do anything wrong.

The iPhone heating up is caused by high CPU usage.

In a desktop computer, RAM (memory) will usually sit in it's slot unattended and in the rare case will have a passive built in heatsink. However the CPU in a computer heats up very fast and requires an active heatsink with special thermal paste to enhance the heat transfer from the CPU to the heatsink. The CPU heats up much faster than memory.